# jQuery Select2 plugin "view more...", hidden search text field questions

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I've a series of questions on jQuery Select2 plugin (I'm very new to Select2, just a day old):

1. I'm getting data via AJAX call (using Select2's ajax feature) and am
   trying to figure out a way to add "view more..." option at the end
   of the dropdown display. Clicking on "view more..." has to take me
   to another separate search page.

   If I could get to the OnSuccess or OnComplete event of loading the AJAX
   call, I could then find the related DIV in the dropdown result and append
   "view more..." div. Is that even possible?

   I don't want to use the "auto scrolling" feature in Select2.
2. I've a search button next to the Select2 dropdown, when users type
   in some characters in the search box, I make the AJAX call and
   display the data. Here, what I also need is when users click on the
   search button, I should take the value typed in the search box and
   make another redirection. The problem I'm facing is this -- since
   Select2 requires the search box be "hidden" for AJAX loads, when
   users search, the search text is not filled in the hidden field, and
   I don't know where/how to get that typed in search text.
3. When AJAX data is filled in, the first item in the dropdown is
   selected, how to not make it selected. Or better yet, if they use
   keys to move up and down in the list, I'd be cool if you reach the
   first item and key up, it focuses on the search text box -- much
   like LinkedIn search box.

Comment: Could you please provide HTML/JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Here is the code for View more issue:

```
$("#select").on('open', function() { 
    $(".select2-results").append('<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-unselectable select2-result-with-children"><div class="select2-result-label view-more">View More</div></li>');
    $(".view-more").on("click", function() { window.location.href = "another_url"; });
});
```

(2) You can access the value of the search box this way:

```
var searchValue = '';
$('.select2-search input').on('keydown', function(e) { 
    searchValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(searchValue);
});

$("#myBtn").on("click", function() { 
    alert(searchValue);
});
```

(3) To unselect default selected option, put this code into `open` function:

```
$('.select2-results .select2-highlighted').removeClass('select2-highlighted');
```

You can check how it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/netme/EW8t7/1/

Comment: Thanks @netme. Answer 1, adding it on open event will show the "view more" even before users have started typing. I guess that's fine, for now I've hidden the li. When displaying the items, I check for the count and if it is more than a number, I show this li.

Comment: Answer 2, ah! I thought about using the keyup/down trick, but assumed the plugin would give us a way to get to what users typed to search. :) The trick worked, but I had to change it to use "keyup" instead of "keydown" as "keydown" was ignoring the last typed character.

Comment: Thanks for the 3rd answer. Let me try it tomorrow and will let you know. Extra points for the jsfiddle. Awesome!

Comment: @libragopi, you are welcome. Please provide a short example next time. You'll get the answer much faster :)